# How can I compile all files in all subdirectories using find?

Tags: shell, find

I have lots of c++ programs that are unrelated to each other and each one being in only one file. Directory structure looks like this:

```
dir1
    program1.cpp
    program1.h
    program2.cpp
    program2.h
dir2
    program3.cpp
    program3.h
    program4.cpp
    program4.h
dir3
    program5.cpp
    program5.h
    program6.cpp
    program6.h
..
```

I'm trying to come up with a shell script to compile them all and give the executables different names. I have been trying this with `find` like so:

```
find . -type f -name *.cpp -exec g++ -llibname '{}' \;
```

This compiles all files but produces `a.out` for each file so I end up with only one executable in the end. How can I strip the file extension and give it as the executable name? (e.g. for `program1.cpp` I need `g++ program1.cpp -o program1`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec sh -c 'g++ {} -o $(basename {} .cpp)' \;
```

This will put all your executables in the directory you launch the command from. If you'd rather keep them in the same directory as the source files, this should do it:

```
find . -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec sh -c 'g++ {} -o $(dirname {})/$(basename {} .cpp)' \;
```

(Remember to quote the filename pattern, otherwise your command will start breaking if you ever have a `.cpp` file in the current directory.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
find . -type f -name '*.cpp'| sed 's/.cpp$//' | xargs make
```

Comment: I don't understand the `xargs make` part. I don't have a makefile for these programs.

Comment: `make /path/to/xyz` would try to run `gcc /path/to/xyz.cpp  -o /path/to/xyz`by default... Try it.. Works on ubuntu at least..

Comment: When I try `make xyz` in `xyz` folder it tries `cc    linux64 xyz.c   -o xyz` and then `cc: error: linux64: No such file or directory`. If somehow I can remove `linux64` I can use this one as well. Quite interesting stuff btw, +1

Comment: err... I am not sure about the preference of `.c` vs `.cpp` though